# How do I quickly refill all the snacks in my inventory in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Is it possible to quickly refill all the snacks in my inventory? How and where do I do this? It is slow and cumbersome to buy them one by one at Convenience Stores.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can quickly refill all snacks in your inventory for free at the following locations. Press the "Take all" button to refill them all at once rather than getting them one by one.

- **[Premium Deluxe Motorsport](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Premium_Deluxe_Motorsport)** (Simeon's shop)

  [image]
  <sub>[Image source](https://www.reddit.com/r/gtaonline/comments/wrpzq4/theres_a_bowl_of_snacks_in_premium_deluxe/)</sub>

  [image]
  <sub>[Image source](https://www.reddit.com/r/gtaonline/comments/wg831j/simeons_shop_essentially_works_as_a_safe_haven_in/)</sub>

The rest are in properties that you need to purchase first:

- **[Executive Office](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Offices)** (CEO building) - talk to your [Assistant](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Assistant) (the receptionist)

  [image]
  <sub>[Image source](https://www.reddit.com/r/gtaonline/comments/op52zh/rockstar_finally_allows_us_to_just_buy_the_entire/)</sub>
- **[Facility](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Facilities)** - talk to the [Facility Receptionist](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Facility_Receptionist)

  [image]
  <sub>[Image source](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Facility_Receptionist)</sub>
- **[Arcade](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Arcades)** - talk to [Wendy](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Wendy)

  [image]
  <sub>[Image source](https://www.reddit.com/r/gtaonline/comments/i7q4l2/in_the_arcade_wendy_now_can_give_you_snacks/)</sub>
- **[Kosatka](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Kosatka)** - at the mess / kitchen

  [image]
  <sub>[Image source](https://www.reddit.com/r/gtaonline/comments/kdorb5/psa_you_can_stock_up_on_free_snacks_inside_the/)</sub>
- **[Auto Shop](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Auto_Shops)**  - at the snack bar

  [image]
  <sub>[Image source](https://www.reddit.com/r/gtaonline/comments/oo1kee/you_can_get_free_snacks_in_the_new_auto_shop/)</sub>
- **[Agency](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Agencies)** - at a table near the waiting area by the reception desk, and at the top floor near the armory

  [image]
  <sub>[Image source](https://www.reddit.com/r/gtaonline/comments/rh3vjw/lpt_you_can_get_free_snacks_in_the_agency_at_the/)</sub>

  [image]
  <sub>[Image source](https://www.reddit.com/r/gtaonline/comments/rim8c3/incase_you_didnt_know_you_can_get_snacks_as_well/)</sub>

Comment: you can also buy some at convenience stores

Comment: @Jan Yep, but it's too cumbersome to buy them one by one at Convenience Stores. At these locations, you can use the "Take All" button.